# Get obj value without hardcoding index in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this obj structure coming from api response, I need to read the various attributes from the data which is again an object. Can someone point me out how this can be done in cleaner way without hardcoding index.

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "id": "2132",
        "type": "year",
        "name": "product",
        "Version": "0.3",
        "data": {
            "CTimestamp": "2018-08-15T21:53:52+00:00",
            "createdBy": "abc",
            "CYCreateTimestamp": "2018-08-15T21:53:52+00:00",
            "Code": "HO",
            "Abbreviation": "xyz",
            "Description": "abcd",
            "cycleYearIdentifier": 2132,
            "id": "2132"
        }
    }
],
"pages": {
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalResources": 1
}
```

}

I want 'code' key out of the "data" object under "objects" - without any index hardcoded. Assume this complete result is stored in result or response variable. I am pretty new to JavaScript and searching something like we have in Python .get over a dictionary to fetch the values through the key if they exist.

`Expected result : "HO"` for this particular response of the API

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "without any index hardcoded"?

Comment: I do not want result = Objects.value(response)[0] and then fetch the value of key by doing result[0].data['code'].

Comment: In your comment, do you mean you don't want an index like `0` or the index/key `code`? Why don't you want to use an index/key? And could you update your question to include an example of the result you want in the end?

Comment: @Cully - Yes I dont want to index like 0. I surely wish to do via key or any inbuilt functions like map/ filter. I also have added the expected result which is HO in this example.

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop over the array of objects and get each `code` value? If not, do you just want the `code` value from the first item in the array, or the last, or something else?

Comment: I do not want to loop over the array, yes I just want the code from the first item inside the array.

Comment: That's just `const code = response?.objects?.[0]?.data?.Code`. It uses a "hardcoded index" but it gives you what you want. You can read about [optional chaining here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Did the posted answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to get the value you want:

```js
const code = response?.objects?.[0]?.data?.Code
```

It will give you your value or `undefined` if any key/index in that chain does not exist.